# ? What does recombobulate mean

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

The word "re-combobul-ate" what does mean ?!

For example (( "re-combobul-ate" area ))

And could anyone recommended a website that can help me to define a new words slang and using by native speakers ..?

Comment: You need to add an example (or a dictionary definition) where the word is actually used, to indicate that it is an actual word, not made up.

Answer (score 3):

Discombobulate is the original nonsense word. It was an invented word. It means 'to destroy, tear apart, fragment'. So to re-combobulate is to recombine, make good what was destroyed, or to undo a bad action.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's derived from the word **discombobulate**, which Oxford Dictionaries defines as "Disconcert or confuse". Since recombobulate replaces the negative prefix "dis" with "re", I expect it means "stop [someone] being disconcerted or confused", perhaps by providing an explanation or reassurance.